# installing packages on pycharm issue

Tags: pycharm

so i was trying to install pygame, i went to the cmd and did the pip install pygame everything was successfully until i went on pycharm, i did everything: i went to file > setting > pythonProjects > interpreter > searched "pygame" > install package
and then was the problem[erorr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bac24.png)

i did what they talled me to do, didnt work, i did everything the google said and didnt work. pls help [erorr details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybTiH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you currently using 3.11? Try rolling back to an earlier version of Python.

*Also, try putting a little more effort into drafting your question. You will be much more likely to get an answer to your question if you make sure you spell everything correctly and use proper grammar. Welcome to stack overflow!

***Edit:*** Here's a link to JetBrains (PyCharm parent company) documentation that covers changing your interpreter: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-reloading-interpreter-paths.html